# Trying to get cookies to prepopulate fields in a form in html

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new to software development and working on code. I am trying to get cookies to populate a field in my form when a user has input into it previously. However not able to work it out.

I have tried to setcookies and getcookies to work , however just cannot populate the form value for some reason. I am getting undefined in the field.

---

```html
<script>
  var today = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days
  function setCookie(name, value) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" +
      expiry.toGMTString();
  }
</script>
<script>
  function storeValues(form) {
    setCookie("phoneNumber", form.phoneNumber.value);
    return true;
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name) {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" autocomplete="on" action="/javascript/getcookie/" onsubmit="storeValues(this)">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>How can we reach you ?</legend>
      <div>
        <label style="width: 40%;" for="phoneNumber">What number can we call 
    you on ? <font color="red">*</font> </label>
        <input name="phoneNumber" type="tel" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="e.g. 0412345678" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='e.g. 0412345678' ; validatePhoneNumber(this)" required>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="post-btn" value="Call Me" />
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value = document.write(getCookie("phoneNumber"));
  </script>
</body>
```

I am expecting to get the number that i previously entered into the form to populate the next time I load the page.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`, just use the result of `getCookie()` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy . that did the trick. Cant believe i did not try that and spend so many hours fixing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `sessionStorage` instead of `cookiee` . 
It saves a lot of coding hack.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>  
<body onLoad="getSession()">
  <form >
    <fieldset>
      <legend>How can we reach you ?</legend>
      <div>
        <label style="width: 40%;" for="phoneNumber">What number can we call 
    you on ? <font color="red">*</font> </label>
        <input name="phoneNumber" type="tel" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="e.g. 0412345678"   required>
        <!-- <button   onClick="validatePhoneNumber(this)">Submit</button> -->
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="post-btn" value="Call Me"  onClick="validatePhoneNumber(this)"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
  <script>
    function validatePhoneNumber(){
        var value = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
        console.log(value)
        sessionStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", value);
    }
    function getSession(){
        console.log("hey");
        var session  = sessionStorage.getItem("phoneNumber");
        document.getElementById("phoneNumber").setAttribute("value" , session);

    }
  </script>
```

**Notice :-** Removed some attribute and field because i am not having that data , you can add according to your necessity  .

For more detail about sessionStorage  , visit [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)